# How to Match last inserted single column against multiple values in child table using Join

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table jobs in my database. and its two  child tables. one job_status_detail and job_assigned.

One job may have multiple status like created,started,completed in job_status_detail with one job_id. 
One job can assigned to multiple user with job_id in job_assigned.

Now i want all job records with last inserted status in job_status_detail.

I use following query

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs`  as `t` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_assigned` as `jobDetail` ON (`jobDetail`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_status_detail` as `job` ON (`job`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE jobDetail.assign_to=1
 Order by job.id
```

but it gives me whole data. if one job has three entry in job_status_detail, it gives me 3 entries.Not last inserted entry.

Result should like one job with one job status(last inserted).

Comment: why do you join job_assigned? if you want only one entry for each job this is a problem and you'll get at least one row for every user which is assigned to the job

Comment: #niyou agree with you

Comment: if your job_status_detail table has a sequenz field you could add a where condition which selects only the matching entry with the highest sequenz number

Comment: job_assigned used for other information. which i get perfectly. but i cant get job_status_detail information properly.

Comment: read again and understand.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `jobs`  as `t` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_assigned` as `jobDetail` ON (`jobDetail`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_status_detail` as `job` ON (`job`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`)  WHERE jobDetail.assign_to=1
 Order by job.id

job_assigned used because i fetch job assigned to particular user

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs`  as `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_assigned` `jobDetail` ON (`jobDetail`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN (select max(id) id from `job_assigned` group by `job_id`) j ON jobDetail.id=j.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_status_detail` `job` ON (`job`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`) 
INNER JOIN (select max(id) id from job_status_detail group by job_id) jsd ON job.id=jsd.id 
WHERE jobDetail.assign_to=1
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put group by tag

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs`  as `t` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_assigned` as `jobDetail` ON (`jobDetail`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_status_detail` as `job` ON (`job`.`job_id`=`t`.`id`) 
GROUP BY job.job_status Order by job.id
```

Comment: your statement dos not work - you cant select * if you group by. Also your statement does not select the last entry from job_status_detail